# I am getting an error when using "rake"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

rake aborted!

```
/home/salmanalam/design/config/routes.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/salmanalam/design/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your `config/routes.rb` (probably on line `62`) regarding an `end` tag or something. When calling `rake` from a Rails project folder, it loads your Rails dependencies as well, so that's why it freaks out on the `routes.rb` error.